# PowerShell function return best practices

Tags: function, powershell, return-value

I have a two part question about best practice in PowerShell with regards to return values from functions. I have a number of complex functions that at a minimum need to return success or failure, plus an array of log items, sometimes just failure logs, sometimes both success and failure logs. And sometimes the function needs to return an object as well. I am doing this now with a $return Tuple as a hash table. So I might have something like this at the end of the function

```
@{
   success = $success
   log = $log
}
```

And use might look like this

```
$functionReturn = Function
if $functionReturn.success {
 stuff
} else {
 Write-Log $functionReturn.log
}
```

I am just curious if there is a better pattern to use here, or if this approach is pretty solid. And if it is, is there any standard for naming conventions and such? As a general rule I try not to reuse "temporary" variables, so rather than $functionReturn used over and over I would have appropriately named variables, so a real world function call might be `$readXML = Read-XML $xmlPath`.
Any suggestions on best practice here is greatly appreciated.

Also, I have seen reference to creating a custom object to do the same thing, but a hash table seems to be cleaner (simpler) from a code standpoint. Is there any reason to be using a custom object instead of the hash table? For example, does a hash table have a size limit when returning, say, a large log array plus a large XML object, for example? Or are there limits to what can be returned by a hash table? Or is it really six of one, half a dozen of the other?

Comment: The answer is do whatever actually works for _your case_. That being said using objects is a very good structured approach. Also, just remember that the return keyword is redundant as _all_ output from functions is returned. As for naming conventions the answer is whatever is descriptive enough so another reader knows what is happening. `$r` is terrible since it means nothing. `$functionReturn` or `$result` is sufficient.

Comment: Matt, point taken about "use what works". Maybe I should rephrase to "is there a condition in which hash tables WON'T work", mostly because I do like consistency, so assuming there is a place where a hash table will fail, and assuming there is no performance issue with custom objects, I would choose to use custom objects everywhere. Whereas, if a hash table will work all the time, and there is no performance penalty for using it, I would use hash tables everywhere because of the simpler setup.
But, you say objects are very "structured". In what way is this different from the hash table?

Comment: This is mostly a personal preference or driven by actual use I would think. I use hashtables when I want to use their methods like `ContainsKey` and the like. PowerShell was designed to work with more complex objects so I use `[pscustomobject]@{}` quite a bit. If there are functional limitations in this regard I have not come across them yet. (They could easily exist.)

Comment: If you do use tuples, a couple of points 1) be careful of Powershell unrolling arrays in a pipeline. If a downstream pipeline command expects an array and you return just a plain array, the downstream won't get the array - they'll get each object in the array separately. 2) This syntax is handy for the caller of a function returning a tuple: `$xmlObj, $otherThing = do-myThing $arg1 $arg2`. 3) Finally when you say 6 of 1 vs 1/2 dozen, it depends on your situation: a) is perf an issue? b) How big is big: 1MB or 100MB? c) how long will the script usually run?

Answer (score 1):

If the caller needs to be notified about a failure I'd throw an exception. IMO a function should only return a boolean value if it implements a status check, i.e. if the boolean value is the actual data. Or if the language doesn't support exception handling.

```
function Check-Something {
  if ($someCondition) {
    $true
  } else {
    $false
  }
}
```

If you need to handle error conditions I would not return error information the same way valid data is returned. I'd do status logging as well as logging of non-fatal errors inside the function and throw exceptions for fatal errors.

```
function Do-Something {
  ...
  Write-Log 'regular log message'
  ...
  if ($somethingUnimportantFailed) {
    # log non-fatal error and continue
    Write-ErrorLog 'unimportant failure'
  }
  ...
  if ($somethingWentTeriblyWrong) {
    # abort what we're doing right now and notify caller
    throw 'error information here'
  }
  ...
  Write-Log 'other regular log message'
  ...
}

try {
  $returnedData = Do-Something
} catch {
  Write-ErrorLog $_.Exception.Message
  # more error handling here
}
```

In general, if something can be handled inside the function I think it should be handled inside the function. I'd only pass information about a failure back to the caller if the failure must be handled by the caller.